# Qt program exited with code -1073741819

Tags: qt, opencv

I am working on a project based on facerecognition using Qt and Opencv in Windows 7. I have come across a really dead end now...I need to train a face recognizer using some images...but whenever I comment out the train statement, the program runs fine but not witholding my purpose...

```
void Dialog::on_btnAdd_2_clicked()
{
    tmrTimer->stop();

    dir=QDir(directory);
    QFileInfoList files;
    QFileInfo file;
    QString filen;


    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    files=dir.entryInfoList();
    int nofiles;
    nofiles=files.size();
    for(int i=0;i<nofiles;i++)
    {
        file=files.at(i);
        filen=file.absoluteFilePath();


        std::string fname = filen.toStdString();

        filen=file.baseName();
        std::string filename=filen.toStdString();

        char* path = new char [fname.size()+1];
        char name[10];

        strcpy(name,filename.c_str());
        strcpy( path, fname.c_str() );

        name[1]='\0';

        ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText(path);
        ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText(name);

        cv::Mat temp=cv::imread(path,-1);
        newImages.push_back(temp);
        newLabels.push_back(atoi(name));
    }


    ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText("Training Started....!!");

    cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer();

    model->train(newImages,newLabels);   ///training statement

    //strcat(home,"\\data.xml");


    //model->save(home);


    ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText("Training Completed!!");
    tmrTimer->start();
}
```

When I run the project and click a button that initiate the above function the process crashes saying...

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: QtTracker3.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5101dde0
  Fault Module Name:    libopencv_core242.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50da6896
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000a38f0
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.3.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

i modified the code as follows taking advices...and got in to another problem...

```
void Dialog::on_btnAdd_2_clicked()
{
    tmrTimer->stop();

    dir=QDir(directory);
    QFileInfoList files;
    QFileInfo file;
    QString filen;

    char name[10];
    int i,j;
    std::string str;


    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    files=dir.entryInfoList();
    int nofiles;
    nofiles=files.size();

    for(i=0;i<nofiles;i++)
        {
            file=files.at(i);
            filen=file.baseName();
            std::string filename=filen.toStdString();
            strcpy(name,filename.c_str());

            for(j=0;name[j]!='-';j++);
            name[j]='\0';

            filen=file.absoluteFilePath();
            str=filen.toStdString();

            cv::Mat offimage=cv::imread(str.c_str(),-1);

            cv::namedWindow("face",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);     //show retrieved image in a window
            cv::imshow("face",offimage);
            cvvWaitKey(1000);

            newImages.push_back(offimage);
            newLabels.push_back(atoi(name));


        }
```

i removed the pointers used within the for loop and stil the very same problem persists...

I also found that qt creator in its issues tab reported an issue:

```
:-1: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code crashes, use a debugger to find out where it crashes. If you don't understand the reason, add the backtrace to the question.

I assume your crash is in the filename handling when looping over the files.
You're opening multiple cans of worms by using char* instead of the std::string or QString and not doing it properly.

For once, this is highly unsafe and also insecure (buffer overflow):

```
    char name[10];
    ...
    strcpy(name,filename.c_str());
```

If the file name is longer than 9, the behavior is undefined (crash, most likely).

You're also leaking memory, as this allocation is never freed: char* path = new char [fname.size()+1];

So I strongly suggest to use QString instead of fiddling with char*. If you need to pass a char* to OpenCV, you can do it like this:

```
const QByteArray ba = filename.toLatin1(); //or toUtf8(), toLocal8Bit(), depending on the encoding you need
... functionTakingChar( ba.constData(), -1 ); // or .data(), if imread() takes a non-const char
```

imread takes a std::string, so:

```
... imread( filename.toStdString(), -1 );
```

Comment: i checked everything else but the statement causing the error is model->train() call...i have named the files as short as possible....I need to train it using the images from the specified path....

Comment: also i created name to print in the display box provided in the gui so that i can make sure that the label fields are not wrong....thanks for the advice :-)

Comment: I have changed as you said...NOw its showing some other error :     Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in reshape, file C:\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 801
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:801: error: (-13) The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed in function reshape

Comment: How do you call imread()? I see it takes a std::string, so I extended the answer. Otherwise try to set a catchpoint at throw to see the bactrace where the exception is thrown.

Comment: I just modefied the funtion and updated the question.. Now its showing error : OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in reshape, file C:\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 801.........I m sure that the input images have dimensions 80*80,,,

Comment: Check the contents of "path". If you're on windows, you might have to use QDir::toNativeSeparators() on the QString to convert "/" to "\". If the path is correct, this is more an issue with your input data and opencv than with C++/Qt.

Comment: yeah path is correct...i tried to display the retrieved image with an opencv cv window...bu tthe input data is grayscale and is of all same dimensions...80*80...i m in dead end..this is my final year project,,,:-(

Comment: full code : https://github.com/kocchumon/qttracker....i doubt it is the problem of the OS??

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with the OS, probably one with your image data or how you use opencv with the data. Anyway, that's not your original question, so you should accept this one (if sufficiently answered) and open a new, opencv-specific one.